# Network Configuration Operator and UAC Issues

Tags: windows-7, networking, uac

I am deploying computers to folks where they use network devices that require them to change the IP at will, but I do not want them to have any other privilege.  To my delight, this group seems to fit well.  However, when I need to come in to do remote work, like mmc it bypasses the UAC, which I understand is by design, however, when I runas ADMIN, it also bypasses.  The user is a standard user and I would like it to have UAC / runas pop up so I can key in the password.  How can this be achieved, if at all possible.  they are using Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want UAC set to a higher setting.

If this is a Domain Computer you can push this by GPO (note that a local administrator can override this setting until the next reboot):

```
Computer Settings\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\User Account Control: Behaviour of the elevation prompt for administrative users.
```

Set this to "Prompt for consent on the secure desktop." or "Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop."

If this is not a Domain Computer, then change the UAC setting to it's Highest setting (this is the equivalent of "Prompt for consent on the secure desktop."), or modify the local security policy.